# Overriding Attacklab script included by script src=

Tags: javascript

I use stackexchange.com, which uses the same editor stackoverflow has (the editor I use now)
When I try to type a special character using right alt + key (other language characters), instead of my special character I get ctrl + key shorcut, e.g. Undo (by pressing right alt + z), numbered list (by pressing right alt + o), hyperlink (by pressing right alt + l) . Is there a way to fix it? Can I disable those shortcuts or fix them so I could use right alt key in my stackexchange site?

I have found the code which handles key shortucts in script /Content/Js/wmd.js. Is it possible to override it somehow in page which include this script by  ?

the "key.metaKey" is Alt key I think and it causes the problem.

```
var setupEditor = function() {

            if (/\?noundo/.test(doc.location.href)) {
                    wmd.nativeUndo = true;
            }

            if (!wmd.nativeUndo) {
                    undoMgr = new wmd.undoManager(function() {
                            previewRefreshCallback();
                            setUndoRedoButtonStates();
                    });
            }

            makeSpritedButtonRow();


            var keyEvent = "keydown";
            if (global.isOpera) {
                    keyEvent = "keypress";
            }

            util.addEvent(inputBox, keyEvent, function(key){

                    // Check to see if we have a button key and, if so execute the callback.
                    if (key.ctrlKey || key.metaKey) {

                            var keyCode = key.charCode || key.keyCode;
                            var keyCodeStr = String.fromCharCode(keyCode).toLowerCase();

                            switch(keyCodeStr) {
                                    case "b":
                                            doClick(document.getElementById("wmd-bold-button"));
                                            break;
                                    case "i":
                                            doClick(document.getElementById("wmd-italic-button"));

           (.............)
```

Comment: Hi Wojtek - This really belongs on meta.stackexchange.com, which is a site designed for questions about stackexchange.

Comment: The editor is from Attacklab (WMD: The Wysiwym Markdown Editor) but its configuration is in included scripts, I've tried to define my own functions in main page (e.g. in head, or footer) but it didn't work - the key listener was already added by wmd scirpt. So I need help from expert in JavaScript. How to remove key listener or override it. This is a programming question I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it with a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) script.  Redefine that function.  You can try first with Firebug, on the console.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that I can't modify included script loaded from /Content/Js/wmd.js . I can only add script at page that has code <script src=Content/Js/wmd.js>.

Comment: But with GM you can run the script in your answer automatically, no? Shouldn't it work?